# Does OkHttp support Link rel=preload header?

Tags: okhttp, http2

My team is working on making our REST API more 'hypermedia' by replacing compound documents with links to related resources. We'd obviously like to use HTTP/2 Server Push to make sure it's as fast as possible. However, because of our hosting provider, we are not able to run HTTP/2.

It seems like the second best option after Server Push would be to have the client prefetch related resources via [Preload](https://w3c.github.io/preload/).

Does anyone know if OkHttp natively supports the `Link rel=preload` header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not. But you should be able to enqueue these yourself by inspecting the headers.